# Pandas value_count where row name

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

```
Count   Month   Fruit
1       Mar     Apple
2       Apr     Kiwi
4       Jun     Orange
8       Dec     Kiwi
12      Nov     Kiwi
4       Oct     Melon
```

With

```
counts = ou['Fruit'].value_counts().to_frame()
```

I get

```
Apple:  1 
Kiwi:   3 
Orange: 1 
Melon:  1
```

I tried something like that

```
counts = ou['Fruit'].where("Kiwi").value_counts()
```

How is it possible to count only the kiwis?
that the output is only 
3 or Kiwis: 3

Answer (score 2):

I recreate your data - and then give you the number of occurrences of 'Kiwi'. If you want the total then just change the count() to sum()

```
import pandas as pd

d={'count':[1,2,4,8,12,4],
'Month':['Mar','Apr','Jun','Dec','Nov','Oct'],
  'Fruit':['Apple','Kiwi','Orange','Kiwi','Kiwi','Melon']}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df[df.Fruit=='Kiwi'].count()
```

Answer (score 1):

If need length of `Kiwi`only sum `True` values only:

```
print (ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi')
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
Name: Fruit, dtype: bool

print ((ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi').sum())
3
```

Same, but a bit complicated:

```
print (ou['Fruit'].value_counts())

Kiwi      3
Melon     1
Orange    1
Apple     1
Name: Fruit, dtype: int64

counts = ou['Fruit'].value_counts().loc['Kiwi']
print (counts)
3
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: dont forget for loc?

Comment: counts = ou.loc[ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi'].value_counts() but I get AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Comment: I think you forget for last string which define column `ou.loc[ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi']` vs `ou.loc[ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi', 'Count']`

Comment: ou.loc[ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi', 'Count'] Works for me. But I get an output like 0.0 3 How can i get only the 3?

Comment: give me a sec. I test it.

Comment: I think you can get `length` of output `print (len(ou.loc[ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi', 'Count']))` or  `print ((ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi').sum())` - same return scalar `3`

Comment: Great Thank you. I have one more question I dont think it is worth to create a new post for this. Kiwi = (ou['Fruit'] == 'Kiwi').sum()  Print("Testing: " + Kiwi) <-- Wont work dunno why. "TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')
"

Comment: It is easy - impossible concanecate `string` with `int` - simply cast to `str` - `print("Testing: " + str(Kiwi))`

Comment: hahaha! okay well thank you didn't thought it would be that easy.